# How to Open Zipped mySQL Data tables using R

Tags: mysql, database, r, zip, datatables

I have been trying to download and open as.table or data frame these zipped mySQL data tables using R and after going through several similar  topics on Stackoverflow, my code is still not working. I would appreciate any help and suggestions tremendously!:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://khipukamayuq.fas.harvard.edu/DataTables/KhipuDB_SQL.zip",temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "KhipuDB_SQL.zip"))
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
cannot locate file 'KhipuDB_SQL.zip' in zip file      '/var/folders/g8/kl3zfkc51rzgg_1xjs4yv4p00000gn/T//RtmpCzBMCi/file65e40df83a3'
unlink(temp)
```

Comment: You'll notice that the contents of the zip file are actually a bunch of mySQL dump files; I strongly doubt there is a way to directly read those into R. The best way to do this would be to read your dump files into a MySQL database (free software), and then use R to connect to the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

These are MySQL dump files, not data tables. They consist of enough information to completely rebuild the database. The database is a set of linked tables. The linkage is described by the schema given here:

http://khipukamayuq.fas.harvard.edu/ProjectDescrERD.html

Now, without knowing exactly what you want to do with this data, its hard to know what to do. Ideally you should load it all into a MySQL server and then you can query it with R's database query tools.

Otherwise, unzip it and look at a typical file, such as `collca_KNOT.sql`. It has a header, and then this:

```
INSERT INTO `KNOT` VALUES (3000003,'S','Z',10,10,1000000,1000000,1,1,'cbrezine','2011-10-09 14:46:14','cbrezin
e','2003-05-28 21:15:26',0,''),(3000003,'L','Z',8,8,1000001,1000001,2,1,'cbrezine','2011-10-09 14:46:14','cbre
zine','2003-05-28 21:15:38',8,'AXD'),(3000004,'E','S',1,1,1000002,1000002,1,1,'cbrezine','2011-10-09 14:46:14'
,'cbrezine','2003-05-28 21:17:02',0,''),(3000006,'S','Z',10,10,1000003,1000003,1,1,'cbrezine','2011-10-09 14:4
6:14','cbrezine','2003-05-28 21:28:04',0,''),(3000007,'E','Z',1,1,1000004,1000004,1,1,'cbrezine','2011-10-09 1
4:46:14','cbrezine','2003-05-28 21:37:40',0,''),(3000009,'S','Z',10,10,1000005,1000005,1,1,'cbrezine','2011-10
```

Each of those tuples is a row in the KNOT table, but the values might refer to lookups in other tables. Now, if all the information you want is in this file, in this INSERT line, then you might get away with reformatting it into a comma-separated format and using `read.table` in R. Just delete everything except this line, replace `),(` with a new line, and remove the start and finish parentheses. It might just work.

Otherwise, and if you need lookups into other tables, you either need a MySQL database server or possibly with a bit of editing you might get it into an SQLite database.

Your best bet might be to work out exactly what tabular format you want out of the database and ask for a CSV dump of that (with lookups expanded) from the data supplier.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response, it was very helpful!I'll probably end up downloading the CSV files from mySQL (I have zero experience with it but I'll delve into all those tutorials and try to figure it out. I guess if not now then when?). Thank you!